# Most elegant way to express random choice between two options in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, colors, random

Given an Array of two elements what is the most elegant way to express a random coin toss to choose between them?

```
var choices = ['#00f', '#ff0'];
document.bgcolor = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
```

Comment: your domain name is misleading if you browse without JavaScript

Comment: JSLint likes var redOrBlue = ["#0000FF", "#FF0000"]; instead of var redOrBlue=new Array("#0000FF", "#FF0000");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.bgColor = (Math.random() < 0.5) ? '#0000FF' : '#FF0000';
```